# Unable to Login for Umbraco Upgrade Authorization (v7)

Tags: content-management-system, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm doing a manual local upgrade of Umbraco from **7.14.1** to **7.15.0**.

I have reached the login screen to authorize the upgrade and I am unable to login. I receive the message "Login failed for user [emailAddress]"

Here's what I have checked so far:

`useLegacyEncoding` is true for both `UmbracoMembershipProvider` and `UsersMembershipProvider`. Changing it to false does not help.

My connection string is valid and the database user has full permissions over the database. I'm using SQL Server.

The user record in the `umbracoUser` table is good. It is not disabled, and `userNoConsole` is showing false (0)

I was able to login with the same username and password before attempting to upgrade.

What am I missing?!!

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming or sw develoment?

Comment: Maybe nothing?! Don't know if this is related to some larger .NET/Database issue that I don't know about. @Shadow

Comment: Nope, login failed message indicates incorrect username and / or password (or error with whatever authentication method you use). SO is for programming and sw development related questions only. You should ask your question on the vendor's support site.